# How modify default mapping from DTO to Data object in OCC Carts Controller [Hybris]?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I want to custom the following OCC rest service:

```
POST /{baseSiteId}/users/{userId}/carts/{cartId}/addresses/delivery
```

I pretend to sent additional information to this service. For that, I've modified the AddressWsDTO parameter. I've added three attributes of RegionWsDTO type to AddressWsDTO class. Also, I've added these attributes in the AddressData and AddresModel classes respectively:

```
@Secured({ "ROLE_CUSTOMERGROUP", "ROLE_CUSTOMERMANAGERGROUP", "ROLE_GUEST", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT" })
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{cartId}/addresses/delivery", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE })
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @ResponseBody
    @ApiOperation(nickname = "createCartDeliveryAddress", value = "Creates a delivery address for the cart.", notes = "Creates an address and assigns it to the cart as the delivery address.")
    @ApiBaseSiteIdUserIdAndCartIdParam
    public AddressWsDTO createCartDeliveryAddress(@ApiParam(value =
            "Request body parameter that contains details such as the customer's first name (firstName), the customer's last name (lastName), the customer's title (titleCode), the customer's phone (phone), "
                    + "the country (country.isocode), the first part of the address (line1), the second part of the address (line2), the town (town), the postal code (postalCode), and the region (region.isocode).\n\nThe DTO is in XML or .json format.", required = true) @RequestBody final AddressWsDTO address,
            @ApiParam(value = "Response configuration. This is the list of fields that should be returned in the response body.", allowableValues = "BASIC, DEFAULT, FULL") @RequestParam(defaultValue = DEFAULT_FIELD_SET) final String fields)
    {
        LOG.debug("createCartDeliveryAddress");
        validate(address, OBJECT_NAME_ADDRESS, getAddressDTOValidator());
        AddressData addressData = getDataMapper().map(address, AddressData.class, ADDRESS_MAPPING);
        addressData = createAddressInternal(addressData);
        setCartDeliveryAddressInternal(addressData.getId());
        return getDataMapper().map(addressData, AddressWsDTO.class, fields);
    }
```

But these new attributes can be mapped to AddressData object because mapping is only allowed for a group of attributes:

```
AddressData addressData = getDataMapper().map(address, AddressData.class, ADDRESS_MAPPING);
```

This group of attributes is defined by the variable: `ADDRESS_MAPPING`.

And this variable is a constant defined in the CartsController:

```
private static final String ADDRESS_MAPPING = "firstName,lastName,titleCode,phone,line1,line2,town,postalCode,country(isocode),region(isocode),defaultAddress";
```

How I can modify this default mapping from DTO to Data object if CartsController is read-only class?

Comment: Why is your CartsController read-only? I think this should definitly editable

Comment: The version 2005 of Hybris doesn't allow to modify this class. It's read-only

Comment: @CesarMiguel this is an OOTB class. You should not edit OOTB classes.Need to extend it in your custom extension

Comment: Hello @sree. I tried to create a children class from CartsController class but it's not possible because this class inside /web/src folder and It's not recognized when I build the project.

Answer (score 1):

The mentioned rest API is deprecated in 2005. You have to use below API

```
public AddressWsDTO createCartDeliveryAddress(@ApiParam(value =
        "Request body parameter that contains details such as the customer's first name (firstName), the customer's last name (lastName), the customer's title (titleCode), the customer's phone (phone), "
                + "the country (country.isocode), the first part of the address (line1), the second part of the address (line2), the town (town), the postal code (postalCode), and the region (region.isocode).\n\nThe DTO is in XML or .json format.", required = true) @RequestBody final AddressWsDTO address,
        @ApiParam(value = "Response configuration. This is the list of fields that should be returned in the response body.", allowableValues = "BASIC, DEFAULT, FULL") @RequestParam(defaultValue = DEFAULT_FIELD_SET) final String fields)
```

These fields holds

```
allowableValues = "BASIC, DEFAULT, FULL"
```

Depends upon the field value attributes will be populated.Mapping configuration is in
dto-level-mapping-v2-spring.xml

```
<bean parent="fieldSetLevelMapping" id="addressWsDTOFieldSetLevelMapping">
    <property name="dtoClass"
              value="de.hybris.platform.commercewebservicescommons.dto.user.AddressWsDTO"/>
    <property name="levelMapping">
        <map>
            <entry key="BASIC" value="id"/>
            <entry key="DEFAULT" value="BASIC,firstName,lastName,titleCode,phone,cellphone,line1,line2,postalCode,country,region,district,town,defaultAddress"/>
            <entry key="FULL" value="DEFAULT,companyName,country(FULL),region(FULL),title,email,visibleInAddressBook,formattedAddress,shippingAddress"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: This configuration is for fields allowed in body response from createCartDeliveryAddress service